# Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr

I am getting weird error while writing the data in the S3 bucket. I don't get this error  regularly. So, not able to figure out what exactly the problem is. 
FYI, i am keeping the configuration of my EMR same everytime. Also, folder in s3 bucket is `NOT` write protected.

```
    insert overwrite directory 's3://logs/apr'
select f.cookie,sum(f.pgvw) as pageview, count(distinct(f.cookie)) as visits from
(
SELECT a.cookie,a.session,count(distinct(a.date_time)) as pgvw from
(
SELECT extcookie(cs_Cookie) as cookie,extsession(cs_cookie) as session,concat(logdate,' ',time) as date_time FROM apr_1 where (uri like '%.aspx%' or uri like '%.html%') and (not(uri like '/lts%')) 
and (extcookie(cs_Cookie)!='-' and extcookie(cs_Cookie)!='  ')
and (extsession(cs_Cookie)!='-' and extsession(cs_Cookie)!='  ')
group by extcookie(cs_cookie),extsession(cs_cookie),logdate,time
)a
group by a.cookie,a.session
)f
where f.pgvw>1
group by f.cookie;
```

Logs of failed job :

```
FINISH_TIME="1373886754825" HOSTNAME="10\.144\.95\.241" ERROR="java\.lang\.RuntimeException: org\.apache\.hadoop\.hive\.ql\.metadata\.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {\"_col0\":\"CWC\=4LD8UplOIb7rD5X3uinVAWd7H\",\"_col1\":7,\"_col2\":1}
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.hive\.ql\.exec\.ExecMapper\.map(ExecMapper\.java:166)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.MapRunner\.run(MapRunner\.java:50)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.MapTask\.runOldMapper(MapTask\.java:441)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.MapTask\.run(MapTask\.java:377)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.Child$4\.run(Child\.java:255)
        at java\.security\.AccessController\.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax\.security\.auth\.Subject\.doAs(Subject\.java:396)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.security\.UserGroupInformation\.doAs(UserGroupInformation\.java:1132)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.Child\.main(Child\.java:249)
    Caused by: org\.apache\.hadoop\.hive\.ql\.metadata\.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {\"_col0\":\"CWC\=4LD8UplOIb7rD5X3uinVAWd7H\",\"_col1\":7,\"_col2\":1}
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.hive\.ql\.exec\.MapOperator\.process(MapOperator\.java:550)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.hive\.ql\.exec\.ExecMapper\.map(ExecMapper\.java:148)
        \.\.\. 8 more
    Caused by: java\.lang\.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java\.util\.ArrayList\.RangeCheck(ArrayList\.java:547)
        at java\.util\.ArrayList\.get(ArrayList\.java:322)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.hive\.serde2\.objectinspector\.StandardStructObjectInspector\.init(StandardStructObjectInspector\.java:118)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.hive\.serde2\.objectinspector\.StandardStructObjectInspector\.<init>(StandardStructObjectInspector\.java:106)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.hive\.serde2\.objectinspector\.ObjectInspectorFactory\.getStandardStructObjectInspector(ObjectInspectorFactory\.java:274)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.hive\.serde2\.objectinspector\.ObjectInspectorFactory\.getStandardStructObjectInspector(ObjectInspectorFactory\.java:259)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.hive\.ql\.exec\.ReduceSinkOperator\.initEvaluatorsAndReturnStruct(ReduceSinkOperator\.java:188)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.hive\.ql\.exec\.ReduceSinkOperator\.processOp(ReduceSinkOperator\.java:197)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.hive\.ql\.exec\.Operator\.process(Operator\.java:471)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.hive\.ql\.exec\.Operator\.forward(Operator\.java:762)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.hive\.ql\.exec\.TableScanOperator\.processOp(TableScanOperator\.java:83)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.hive\.ql\.exec\.Operator\.process(Operator\.java:471)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.hive\.ql\.exec\.Operator\.forward(Operator\.java:762)
        at org\.apache\.hadoop\.hive\.ql\.exec\.MapOperator\.process(MapOperator\.java:531)
        \.\.\. 9 more
```

Answer (score -1):

When your SELECT or GROUP BY clauses contain two or more fields or aggregates that differ only in case (e.g., both extsession(cs_cookie) and extsession(cs_Cookie)), the optimizer will try to combine the fields even though the ExecMapper does not. This causes the error you're seeing.

You can confirm or deny that this is the cause of your problem by converting all instances of "cs_cookie" to "cs_Cookie" (or vice-versa) and trying the same query again. If you no longer get the error, it is due to this optimization problem.

Comment: It's not an answer, if you have questions or suggestions to author of question, please use comments.